# How can I list all 1st row values in an Excel spreadsheet using OpenPyXL?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Using the OpenPyXL module with Python 3.5, I was able to figure out how many columns there are in a spreadsheet with:

```
In [1]: sheet.max_column
Out [1]: 4
```

Then I was able to list the values in each of the 4 cells with:

```
In [2]: for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A1':'D1']:
            for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
                print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
Out [2]: A1 Dog, B1 Cat, C1 Hamster, D1 Bigger Dog
```

But is there a way to skip the first step and simply list the values for `x` number of columns?

I wouldn't have known to iterate over `['A1':'D1]` if I didn't know how many columns there were. If there were say 200 columns it would be a time waster to calculate the 200th letter/number after `['A1']`.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your sample to get what you want. But it's not recommended to do it this way!

```
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A1':sheet.cell(row=1, column=sheet.max_column).coordinate]:
      for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
          print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
```

---

**Use one of the following samples:**

Sampel1: Iter all columns per row, break after the first row.

```
  for rows in ws.rows:
    for cell in rows:
      print('cell %s %s' % (cell.coordinate,cell.value))
    break
```

**More programatical control:**

Sample2: Iterates all columns only from the row given by min/max_row arguments,
ends after one row.

Arguments min/max_row can point to any row, even also outside data.

```
  for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
      print('cell %s %s' % (cell.coordinate,cell.value))
```

*** Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 ***

Answer (score 2):

If you need to iterate through all the rows or columns of a file, you can instead use the `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.rows()` property, or the `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.columns()` property.

See [Manipulating a workbook in memory](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells).

Comment: Link is broken.  Please include relevant information in post, as well as link